# Xcode 5.1 - iOS 7.1 error

Tags: objective-c, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I had successfully built an app with xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.1 SDK. But yesterday I updated Xcode to 5.1. And now when I try to build for releasing, it throws so many errors.

These are the errors.

1. types.h - User Defined Issues - Architecture not supported
2. _types.h - User Defined Issues - Architecture not supported
3. Semantic issue - Unknown type name '__int64_t', Unknown type name '__int32_t', Unknown type name '__uint64_t', Unknown type name '__uint32_t', Unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'.. etc.

I think these errors are from iPad-prefix.pch, UIKit.h, iPhoneOS6.1.sdk and some frameworks. I have no clue how to fix it.

The Deployment target is 6.1 and Base SDK is 7.1. Architecture is Standard Architecture armv7, armv7s, arm64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, try remove from "Standart Architectures" arm64. And leave arm64 in "Valid Architectures"
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Merchi. But is that the correct solution? Will there be any issues on 64bit Macs?

Comment: I think you can read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html