# Force Xcode 5.1 to build with 32-bit architecture

Tags: ios, xcode

My app is not optimized for 64-bit architecture yet. I need to release one build with 32-bit architecture, that will run on iPhones 5S with 32-bit architectur. In Xcode 5.0, I just exluded armv64 from Architectures in Build settings, but this does not seem to work under Xcode 5.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424568/xcode-5-1-ios-7-1-error/22424961?noredirect=1#comment34115015_22424961

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to stop xcode5.1 building for 64bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316310/how-to-stop-xcode5-1-building-for-64bit)